# How do you show the exception handler in a class diagram?

Tags: design, design-patterns, uml

I have one exception handler class. I want to show this class in the uml -- class diagram. But, I do not know how to represent relationship between class `<X>` and exception handler class. How can I represent relationship between class in class diagram?

Answer (score 1):

From what I've seen, **stereotype** is usually used to represent the relationship to an exception.

> a better approach would be to use UML’s stereotype notation with the keyword exception as the stereotype enclosed in guillemets, as in «exception».

<sup>*Source: [How can I represent an exception in UML?](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=62790)*</sup>

[This answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8077507/240613) also suggests stereotypes, but uses `<<throws>>` instead. The author is confident that it's ok to use a stereotype which doesn't exist conventionally, and in this particular case, I agree with him.

As for the proper term, given that a stereotype can be a noun or a verb, both `<<exception>>` and `<<throws>>` seem equally correct. The proper terminology also depends on the language you use. For example in Python, you don't *throw*, but *raise* an error or an exception, so `<<raises>>` looks as the most appropriate one; unless your intention is to separate errors and exceptions, in which case `<<exception>>` and `<<error>>` may be more expressive.

Finally, [Agile Modeling suggests](http://www.agilemodeling.com/style/classDiagram.htm) (search for Figure 4) to embed the name of the exception like this:

```
+ findAllInstances(): Vector {exceptions=NetworkFailure, DatabaseError}
```

but IMO, while it's well suited for well-known exceptions used by the framework, it is too poor for custom exceptions you have created, because the relation is not visual enough.

Answer (score 1):

One take on it is that the exception handlers are not a part of the problem domain, but rather a part of the non-functional requirements. That is, the architecture of the system. In that sense, they don't really belong in a class diagram of a domain model any more than a Logger class belongs there. (Or a BeanFactory, or garbage collector, etc.)

Class diagrams display information about classes in the model as well as relationships between them. But an exception handler has a relationship with many or all of the classes -- in that the control flow might suddenly halt and go to the exception handler instead. Worse still, the relationship between the exception handler and the domain classes is managed by the *framework* of the application, so there isn't a direct relationship to the domain classes (by design).

If your class diagram is for the framework classes, then it's easy. There will most likely be some sort of controller with a "has a" relationship to the exception handler. But if the class diagram is for the domain model, there are lots of bits from the background I wouldn't put in the class diagram.